# Twilio-video: how to tell if a track is a screenshare?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

Right now in "room.on('trackAdded')", I can't tell if the track which was added is a screenshare or not. Is there a way to tell?

Answer (score 9):

Thank you, [@philnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28376/philnash), I was using suggested behaviour.

But with Twilio 2.x it seems to be broken. And according to [documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.0.0-beta11/docs/LocalVideoTrack.html) it's required to specify options (add a name) during local track creation:

```js
const newScreenLocalTrack = new Twilio.Video.LocalVideoTrack(newScreenTrack, {name: 'screen'})
```

and then just publish created track without any options:

```js
localParticipant.publishTrack(newScreenLocalTrack)
```

Comment: Thank you @Liana! Your answer is really helpful!

Comment: Thank you Liana! This is much better than philnash's answer as this sets the name pre-publishing the track. Allowing to store the track in various places pre-publishing, and manipulating it in other ways.

Answer (score 8):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I am aware each track is either a VideoTrack or an AudioTrack. A screenshare will be a VideoTrack, but other than that there is nothing to tell it apart from another VideoTrack from a camera source.

**Edit**

After some further research I've found the following:

You can set a [name for `LocalTrack`s](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.14.0/docs/global.html#LocalTrack) which shows up on the remote side. For example, if you create a new `MediaStreamTrack` which is the screen, and [publish that track](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.14.0/docs/LocalParticipant.html#publishTrack__anchor) to your local participant, then you can set a name for it.

```
localParticipant.publishTrack(screenVideoTrack, { name: 'screen' })
```

Then, when you receive the `trackAdded` event you can inspect the track's name property:

```
room.on('trackAdded', (track, participant) => {
  console.log(track.name);
});
```

Comment: This is not helpful at all. I need to place user's camera feed at one location and screen feed at a different one. There should be a way to tell which is which and who's camera and screen it is.

Comment: @Nishant you made me question myself, thank you. Turns out you can tell, by setting a name for the tracks. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: ha ha, I got it figured, came here to add to the answer. Glad to see you've done it better. Thanks +1.